# Zipping a file and saving it to local disk using Actionscript 3 & FZip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cc

i made a flash desktop application that requires the user to save a file to his computer, in this case i have a lot of images and i want the user to save them on his computer, the images are on a folder called "imgs", i'm using one image in this case, i tried to do the following using FZip:

```
import deng.fzip.*;
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.filesystem.File;

//retrieve the image from the "imgs" folder
var myfile:File = new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop/zip/imgs/myimage.png");

//zipping the image
var zip:FZip = new FZip(); 
zip.addFile(myfile.name, myfile.data);

//saving the image to the user's desktop
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
zip.serialize(ba);
ba.position = 0;
var finalZIP:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("myfile.zip");
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(finalZIP, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(ba);
fs.close();
```

the result is a zip file in the desktop, named "myfile.zip", with and image named "myimage.png", but when i unzip the file the image is empty, i tried to do the same with a text file, the text file is there zipped, but with nothing inside it.
Any idea what might cause this problem?

Comment: As your code goes, you put nothing into the image because **File.data** property is initially empty: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#data

Comment: Thanks , but still there is a problem because the files that i want the user to download have many extensions, images, txt, ppt... how can i convert the content inside the files to a ByteArray to put it in the File.data, whatever the extention is?

Comment: Please clarify the problem. You load the file and it is **somehow** not a **ByteArray**?

Comment: what i want to do is: 1- load a file from a directory i specify, 2- zip the file, 3-  put the zip file in the user's desktop. this is what i want to achieve when i tried this code.

Comment: I have already pointed out that you **didn't** load the file.

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm missing, is there a method in the File() class that loads the file, or should i use a method in the FileReference() class, or something else?

Comment: **File** class has **File.load(...)** method, inherited from **FileReference**. If that does not work (you should test it), you can always resort to **FileStream** class or **URLLoader** class.

Comment: Many thanks, problem solved.

Comment: Please share your solution for benefit of the site (share it as an answer to your own question).  Mark it as the accepted answer once you do.